# Permuting Matrices in Ocaml

Tags: matrix, ocaml, permutation

So, I have to do this task

permute: ‘a list list -> int list -> int list ->
‘a list list =

that takes a square n×n matrix represented as a list of lists as the first parameter
and returns a matrix with rows in order given by the list of integers as the
second parameter and columns in order given by the list of integers as the third
parameter. The second and third parameter each represent a permutation of
the first n numbers.

Example:
permute [[1;2;3];[4;5;6];[7;8;9]] [2;3;1] [1;3;2];;
- : int = [[4;6;5];[7;9;8];[1;3;2]]

My code so far is like this:

```
let fun a i =
let elem id = List.nth a (id-1) in
List.map elem i
```

This works as a list but I need it to work as a list of lists.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(You can't have a function named `fun` in OCaml. `fun` is a so-called reserved word. I will rename it to `perm`.)

Your function has this type:

```
val perm : 'a list -> int list -> 'a list = <fun>
```

In other words, it works for any list at all. This includes a list of lists.

For example:

```
# perm [1;2;3;4] [4;3;2;1];;
- : int list = [4; 3; 2; 1]
# perm [[1;1]; [2;2]; [3;3]; [4;4]] [4;3;2;1];;
- : int list list = [[4; 4]; [3; 3]; [2; 2]; [1; 1]]
```

So, the hint is to map this `perm` function over the initial list, then to apply this perm function again to the result.